# How to get the application roles from AzureAD to be returned in ClaimsIdentity?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, .net-7.0

> **Summary**

Currently writing an app that needs to authenticate against Microsoft Azure AD.  This app will be proprietary to the end-user for whom I am mandated to develop it.  In the end, the app registration will be ultimately done within my client's Azure AD, and it is a single tenant application.

I created app roles within the app config as follows:
[image: List of app roles within Azure AD]

> **homeworks**

I checked and performed several searches on GitHub, Microsoft Learn, here on StackOverflow and other forums and can't seem to find anything that allows me to get the roles like [**MSAL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/) does.

I found many outdated resources with examples, but nearly no examples found for .Net 7.

> **MSAL with Microsoft.Identity.Web**

Using MSAL, it seems that I just need to write the following within the composition root (Program.cs or StartUp.cs).

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes: new string[] { "user.read" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

With proper configuration section in **appsettings.json**.

```
{
  "AzureAD": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "ClientId": "[Azure AD Application Id]",
    "TenantId": "[Azure AD Tenant Id]",
    "ClientCredentials": [
      {
        "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
        "ClientSecret": "[Client Secret]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

And this signs the user in flawlessly and I also have the role claim shown above, that is, ***PurchaseManager.Admin***.  What doesn't work well is that when I sign out, it doesn't just sign the user out of the app, but it also signs the user out of everything Microsoft which isn't the expected behaviour.

As such, I created my own OAuth2.0/OpenId authenticator and use it like so:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o => {
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(o => {
        o.Cookie.Name = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Trim()}-{MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}";
    })
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
        o.ClientId = "[ClientId]";
        o.ClientSecret = "[ClientSecret]";
        o.TenantId = "[TenantId]";
        o.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
    });
```

This works flawlessly as expected to sign the user in and out, but I just can't figure out how to get the application roles claim from Azure AD.

Here's my authenticator Options class initializer.

> **MicrosoftAccountOptions**

```
    public class MicrosoftAccountOptions : OAuthOptions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new <see cref="MicrosoftAccountOptions"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public MicrosoftAccountOptions() {
        AuthorizationEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint;
        CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-aad");
        TokenEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.TokenEndpoint;
        UserInformationEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.UserInformationEndpoint;
        JwksUri = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.JwksUri;                

        Scope.Add(MicrosoftAccountScope.OpenId);
        Scope.Add(MicrosoftAccountScope.Profile);
        Scope.Add(MicrosoftAccountScope.Email);

        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("iss", "iss");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("cloud_instance_name", "cloud_instance_name");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("cloud_instance_host_name", "cloud_instance_host_name");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("cloud_graph_host_name", "cloud_graph_host_name");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("msgraph_host", "msgraph_host");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("aud", "aud");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("exp", "exp");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("iat", "iat");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("auth_time", "auth_time");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("acr", "acr");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("nonce", "nonce");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("preferred_username", "preferred_username");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("tid", "tid");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("ver", "ver");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("at_hash", "at_hash");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("c_hash", "c_hash");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("email", "email");
        //  Below are the attempts to claim the roles, and I just can't get them.
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("roles", "roles");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Role, "role");
        ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("wids", "wids");

        SaveTokens = true;
    }
}
```

> **MicrosoftAccountHandler**

In the handler, the ClaimsIdentity returned will not contain the role claim.

```
public class MicrosoftAccountHandler : OAuthHandler<MicrosoftAccountOptions> {
    public MicrosoftAccountHandler(IOptionsMonitor<MicrosoftAccountOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, AuthenticationProperties properties, OAuthTokenResponse tokens) {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

        var response = await Backchannel.SendAsync(request, Context.RequestAborted);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new HttpRequestException($"An error occured when retrieving Microsoft Account information ({response.StatusCode}). Please check if authentication information is correct.");

        using var payload = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        var context = new OAuthCreatingTicketContext(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties, Context, Scheme, Options, Backchannel, tokens, payload.RootElement);
        context.RunClaimActions();
        await Events.CreatingTicket(context);

        return new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties, MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

I'd preferrably work with my own authenticator as the app I'm writing doesn't require all that the Azure AD offers.  It is too complex for nothing, tmho.

> role assignments

As per @PramodValavala's comment, here are the role assignments.

[image: role assignments]

Besides, no role is returned in the claims when authenticated.  But scopes are added like:  *Application.ReadWrite.All*, *AppRoleAssignments.ReadWrite.All*.

So, what am I missing?  How can I get the roles assigned to the user?

Comment: Could you confirm if you have assigned a user to a role and if the roles value is present in the token? You can use the [`jwt.ms`](https://jwt.ms) service to decode the token value and inspect its contents.

Comment: @PramodValavala, thx for pointing it out.  App role is assigned.  Plz check question edit ("role assignments").

Comment: @PramodValavala, roles don't seem to be found in the token.  Instead, I can find scopes like :  "Application.ReadWrite.All, AppRoleAssignments.ReadWrite.All, etc." but no role at all.